# http://localhost/mod_cluster-manager gives page not found error. (File does not exist: mod_cluster-1.2.0/httpd-2.2/htdocs/mod_cluster-manager)

Tags: apache, jboss6.x, mod-cluster

Hi I'm trying to configure `mod_cluster` with `jboss AS 6.1`. My clusters are working fine. But I try to view `/mod_cluster-manager` page it gives me page not found error. Apache is up and running and I see `It works!` page.

Mod_cluster version `mod_cluster-1.2.0`.
This is the url I try to access and get `404 error`. `http://localhost/mod_cluster-manager`

Apache run on `port 80`

here is my `httpd.conf` file snipt.

```
 <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so

LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

# MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS
# Adjust to you hostname and subnet.
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 127.0.0.1:6666
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666>
 #   <Location />
 #    Order deny,allow
 #    Deny from all
 #    Allow from 127.0.0.1
 #   </Location>
    <Directory />
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0

    </Directory>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    #ServerAdvertise on http://127.0.0.1:6666
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
    #AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
    EnableMCPMReceive

    <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0
       AllowDisplay On
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Apache `error_log`

```
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:16 2013] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:16 2013] [notice] Child 2828: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:16 2013] [info] Child 2828: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Advertise initialized for process 1940
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Server built: Feb  9 2012 22:24:33
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6012
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(477): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] mod_advertise.c(577): [6012 - 1940] in child post config hook
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 200 and sending it to child process 6012
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(398): Child 6012: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 196 and sending it to child process 6012
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(595): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 6012
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(554): Child 6012: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 6012 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1914): proxy: initialized worker 0 in child 6012 for (*) min=0 max=64 smax=64
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [info] Child 2828: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 2828: Released the start mutex
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [info] Child 2828: 64 threads blocked on the completion port
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Starting thread to listen on port 6666.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:17 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [notice] Child 2828: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:18 2013] [notice] Child 2828: Child process is exiting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [info] Child 6012: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [info] Child 6012: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Advertise initialized for process 1940
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Server built: Feb  9 2012 22:24:33
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6452
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:44 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(477): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] mod_advertise.c(577): [6452 - 1940] in child post config hook
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [notice] Child 6452: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(398): Child 6452: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 200 and sending it to child process 6452
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 196 and sending it to child process 6452
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(595): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 6452
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(554): Child 6452: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 6452 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1914): proxy: initialized worker 0 in child 6452 for (*) min=0 max=64 smax=64
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [notice] Child 6452: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [notice] Child 6452: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Released the start mutex
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:45 2013] [info] Child 6012: 64 threads blocked on the completion port
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [notice] Child 6012: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [notice] Child 6012: Child process is exiting
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [notice] Child 6452: Starting thread to listen on port 6666.
[Wed Nov 27 10:56:46 2013] [notice] Child 6452: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

some times I see this error also.

```
[Wed Nov 27 10:52:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Downloads/openlogic-mod_cluster-1.2.0-windows-ia32-bin-1/mod_cluster-1.2.0/httpd-2.2/htdocs/mod_cluster-manager
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

By your configuration alone, likely that the manager URL is `http://localhost:6666/mod_cluster-manager`.

Comment: This is the right answer, with a tiny amendment that it's actually 

    ```http://127.0.0.1:6666/mod_cluster-manager```